# Windows phone 7 online radio app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, audio-streaming

I am trying to develop application that will be able to stream and play some of the radio stations that have online strem,
my question is can i stream an audio from source like this one: http://www.radiostanica.com/sr/radio/429/Biker_Radio
Ia m trying to open it with audio player, but i am not having any experience with this one, so if someone can help with advice or maybe idea and sample.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the issue of a seekable stream and MediaStreamSource, you need to write a custom stream, SeekableStream, that wraps around any other Stream and makes it appear seekable by using an internal memory stream.

You can see it in action [here](http://prefix.teddywino.com/post/SilverlightMediaKitLiveDemo.aspx) where it can play a MP3 files located locally on your machine or on the web. Source for the library and demo is now up on [CodePlex](http://salusemediakit.codeplex.com/)